# Modal in Rails rendering create information instead of my edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, erb

I'm having an issue with rendering my records inside a modal for editing when an edit button is press. It is instead rendering a new FormObject.

E.g. I have a `work_sample_form` instance variable set to WorkSampleForm.for_work_sample(work_sample) which build out my work sample object. But when i check the modal, the information in the form is like for a new WorkSampleForm.new(). Here some applicable code for it to make more sense:

this route is hit on the controller as I see the printed @work_sample on my server (I have a before_action method to set the @work_sample)

```
#work_sample_controller
  def edit
    p @work_sample
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

my edit.js.erb is as follows:

```
$html = "<%= escape_javascript(render '/work_samples/form', work_sample_form: WorkSampleForm.for_work_sample(@work_sample), remote: true, action: :edit) %>";
$("#work-sample-form").modal('open')
```

My `work_sample_form` FormObject model as follows:

```
#work_sample_form model
  def self.for_user(user)
    new(user_id: user.id,
        title: 'New Title')
  end

def self.for_work_sample(work_sample)
    p new(
      work_sample_id: work_sample.id,
      title: work_sample.title,
      description: work_sample.description,
      start_date: work_sample.start_date,
      end_date: work_sample.end_date,
      user_id: work_sample.user_id,
      tag_ids: work_sample.tag_ids,
      attachments: work_sample.attachments
    )
  end
```

When I click my 'Edit' button on my modal, I see the title as 'New Title' which I assume is initialize from below which is from trigger a create option:

```
<%= render 'work_samples/form_modal', work_sample_form: WorkSampleForm.for_user(current_user), remote: true %>
```

Is this the right way to populate a modal with information for an edit? Sorry if this seems newbie, still a bit new to Rails.

Comment: render('work_samples/form_modal', work_sample_form: WorkSampleForm.for_user(current_user), remote: true).html_safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops found my mistake. Forgot to swap out the new $html and override it as the new html content in the container.

e.g.:

```
$html = "<%= escape_javascript(render '/work_samples/form', work_sample_form: WorkSampleForm.for_work_sample(@work_sample), remote: true, action: :edit) %>"
$container = $("#work-sample-form")

$container.html($html)

$container.modal('open')
```